# Many-to-many relationship on the same table

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

I try get all related records from `many-to-many` table.

I have two tables:

1. Table `post` has `id` and `title` column.
2. Table `post2post` has `parent_id` and `child_id` column.

`post2post` have many-to-many relationship on the same table `post`.

For example, if `post id=1` is the parent `post id=2` and `post id=3`

```
parent_id   child_id
1           2
1           3
```

**And when I select `post id=3`, I should have `post id=1` and `post id=2`**

Here is my `DQL` query

```
         SELECT p as post
         FROM AppBundle:Post p
         WHERE p in (
            SELECT parent
            FROM AppBundle:Post p2
            LEFT JOIN p2.parentPost as parent
            WHERE p2 = (:post)
         )
         OR p in(
            SELECT child
            FROM AppBundle:Post p3
            LEFT JOIN p3.childPost as child
            WHERE p3 = (:post)
        )
```

I know, this query does not work properly, but it's all I could do

Comment: Many to many relationships require 3 tables. [www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

Comment: If you use a manyToMany, you don't need to declare a post2post entity, it's done in silently by the relation itself.